# syntax to add value to a vector in a constructor in c# core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Well, it's pretty simple question.
I'm building an API with .NET Core, I have a model and a repository, after declaring the model I'm creating the functions and so on in the repository, I also have a constructor in the repository for easier testing and initializing the database.

```
public EntriesRepository()
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
   _entries.Add(i, new entry
   {
    id = i,
     product[] = ??
     quantity[] = ??
    });
}
```

And here is my model

```
Public Class entry {
 public int id {get;set;}
 public int?[] product {get;set;}
 public double?[] quantity {get;set;}
}
```

I can initialize the other values of my model without any issues (so I ommited then), but when it's the arrays, they never compile, how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Just use `product = // some expression resulting in an array` - it's not clear why you've used `product[] = ...`

Comment: (As a side-note, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: you don't need to put `[]` just `product = ??,
     quantity = ??` since you are just setting values in the propeties

Comment: Do you want the arrays to be empty? Populated? It's not clear what your requirements are.

Comment: well I just need to add an integer to every value in the array

Comment: @Universal - every value in the array? Are you saying that that the arrays are already instantiated? Could you at least show a Java example comparable to what you are looking for?